# saslprep warning when using MongoClient.connect()

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm writing a NodeJS/express API and am facing the following warning when connecting to mongo server:

```
Warning: no saslprep library specified. Passwords will not be sanitized
```

Found no mention of this warning in documentation or github/google - is that OS (linux) library missing, or node package?

This is the connection code sample:

```
const client = await MongoClient.connect(`mongodb://${auth[0]}:${auth[1]}@${url}/admin`, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});
this.db = client.db(database);
```

How can I get rid of it?

**Additional information:**

Mongodb server: docker mongo:latest, resolved to 4.0.4 as of now

mongodb library: 3.1.9

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Just install the `saslprep` package and the warning will go away.

The `mongodb` package looks for the `saslprep` package, but works without it; it's an optional dependency.

If you look in the mongodb source:

```
let saslprep;
try {
  saslprep = require('saslprep');
} catch (e) {
```

And, later:

```
if (!saslprep) {
    console.warn('Warning: no saslprep library specified. Passwords will not be sanitized');
}
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, because I use webpack for bundling. For webpack you need to add saslprep to "externals" additionally or import explicitly.

Comment: Dear Michael, I suggest you checking saslprep source code to see how they "innovatively" use "code-points.mem" checks with require before sending REPORTS. The recipe with externals and including saslprep from outside webpack works exactly for the reason how the library implements import (see https://github.com/reklatsmasters/saslprep/commit/bcc7396db78621fe150b26036f872dc8d266be6a). The problem doesn't exist for library version 1.0.1 and below and was introduced in 1.0.2, thus for 1.0.1 the way from your comment is enough (i.e. installing a library). Thank you.

Comment: Btw, there is duplicate thread on StackOverflow that has the solution with externals and explanation, for anyone interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58697934/webpack-how-do-you-require-an-optional-dependency-in-bundle-saslprep. Disclaimer: I haven't invented the solution.

Comment: @metamaker you genius! i haven't had this kind of problems before, that externals trick saved me. I have been struggling with this issue for hours now, now is finally solved thank to you

Answer (score 12):

Please use this command in your app. It worked for me. Hope it help you.

```
npm install saslprep --save
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to install `@mongodb-js/saslprep` instead of `saslprep` in a project which still uses Mongoose v6.