# Webpack - How do you require an optional dependency in bundle (saslprep)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, webpack

I am using webpack to bundle a number of back-end scripts into a single file during my deployment process.

When connecting to the MongoDB database there is an optional dependency, which throws a warning if it is not included.

```
Warning: no saslprep library specified. Passwords will not be sanitized
```

In my development environment this error is easily resolved by installing the optional dependency.

```
npm install saslprep --save
```

However when bundling with webpack the optional dependency is not included and the warning persists in the production deployment. I can trace the cause of this easily enough, the mongodb library is requiring this as an optional dependency:

```js
let saslprep;
try {
  saslprep = require('saslprep');
} catch (e) {
  // don't do anything;
}
```

I have tried following the webpack documentation using shimming, externals, plugins and frankly am quite lost as to the correct approach to resolve this issue. Here is my current webpack.config file (attempting to require this as a plugin).

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/api/index.ts',
    target: 'node',
    mode: 'production',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.tsx', '.ts', '.json']
    },
    output: {
    filename: 'api.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/fsevents/),
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/blessed/),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            saslprep: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/saslprep/index.js")
        })
    ],
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Brendan for steering me in the right direction. Ultimately the answer was found here: http://www.matthiassommer.it/software-architecture/webpack-node-modules/

The key piece of information being:

> Webpack’s compiler converts the require() call to its own **webpack_require**(). At runtime it looks into its internal module registry.

Following the steps outlined therein the resolution becomes:

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/api/index.ts',
    target: 'node',
    mode: 'production',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.tsx', '.ts', '.json'],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'api.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/fsevents/),
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/blessed/),
    ],
    externals: {
        "saslprep": "require('saslprep')"
    }
};
```

***Please note that in my testing the quotes around "saslprep" do appear to berequired when importing externals.***

Comment: How did you instruct your program to include the `saslprep` module outside of your bundle? Externals just remove a module from your bundle. From the article you quoted above: "Instead, the created bundle relies on that dependency to be present in the consumer’s environment." We are working with the serverless framework and it doesn't seem easy.

Answer (score 4):

The module `saslprep` is included into the bundle but it will fail to load because it's trying to read the file `code-points.mem` that doesn't exist.

You have to copy this file from the `saslprep` package into the root of your project (the relative path must be `../code-points.mem`).

It doesn't matter if you copy it by hand or with the `copy-webpack-plugin` plugin.

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                {
                    from: require.resolve("saslprep/code-points.mem"),
                    to: "../code-points.mem"
                }
            ]
        })
    ],
}
```

Comment: Nice work @Vincent, this is a very deep and well-researched answer! The first one that actually explains what happened.

Comment: This is the actual answer IMHO. Marking saslprep in externals doesn't include it in the pack - which doesn't fix the underlying emitWarning from the mongodb client.

As @Vincent mentions, if grepping the packed code saslprep is included by webpack. Using the copy plugin (to copy code-points.mem) got it working for me and stopped mongodb client emitting warnings. Make sure you follow the point of it being relative to the handler (I didn't and it didn't work at first until I followed the instructions exactly)

Answer (score 1):

webpack should be 'seeing' that `require('saslprep')` code and bundling saslprep. You can confirm this by looking at the file(s) created by webpack and searching for something distinctive from the library's source code. I would look at the MongoDB code that is checking for that dependency -- it may be that the way they're checking that it exists doesn't work with the way that webpack bundles and defines the dependency. (Most authors of node libraries are probably not thinking about how the code will operate when bundled -- webpack can be used for Node, but it rarely is.) If that's the case, you might be able to reverse-engineer what the code is checking for and put it in place via an alias, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Brendan. It does indeed look like webpack is seeing ```require('saslprep')``` and including it in the bundle. When you say via an alias you mean something along the lines of what is outlined [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias)?

Comment: That's what I was referring to, yes. But I'm not sure if that will end up helping -- you'd want to look at the source code of the mongo-related module that is checking for the existence of `saslprep`. How is it making that check, what's it looking for? You're going to want to give it what it's looking for, so it all depends on how that check is written. Feel free to share that check's implementation here for help with a 'fix'

Comment: Hi Brendan - don't feel a need to look at this as I found a solution using Externals Above. But for posterity the checks made by the source code can be seen here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/master/lib/core/auth/scram.js

Answer (score 1):

I you use the webpack-node-externals package, you can also do this:

```
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals")

...

const webpackConfig = {
  ...
  externals: [nodeExternals({
    allowlist: ['saslprep']
  })],
  ...
}
```